# Quickfixj- Socketinitiator reference memory allocation whn no session logged on

Tags: quickfixj

I have below code lines ,using quickfixj 2.3

Initiator ini= new SocketInitiator(...)
Ini.start ()

Now my question is , we are not calling any stop method. On disconnect or connect exception, canLogon is false everytime.
So will that reference is eligible for garbage collection as noone session logged on. As little confused, as the session is still present

Comment: The Session will be there regardless of whether it is connected or not. It still holds information like current sequence numbers etc.

Comment: Yeah understand. I wanted to know about gc. If nobody is logged on, in that case, is it eligible for garbage collection or not ?

Comment: No. Why should it be eligible for GC if it is still used? The `Session` will be existent as long as the connector is not stopped.

Comment: Ohk. Thanks Christoph John . So now code in place  thank you very much.